# Got all the same ID's from api, what can i do to make them count itself?

Tags: php, xml

I'm getting all the data from GT api (xml) from link: http://api.gametracker.rs/demo/xml/server_info/217.26.212.10:20021/

Especially for players list, as you can see, all the PID's are 0, i'm displaying them in table with following code:

```
<?php
foreach( $players as $player ) {
echo "
<ul>
<li id=\"number\">$player->pid.</li>
<li id=\"nickname\">$player->name</li>
<li id=\"score\">$player->score</li>
<li id=\"time\">$player->time</li>
</ul>";
}
?>
```

What I can do to make pid count itself for as many as found players in xml file?

Comment: You want to know the total number of players?

Comment: Add an increment var to the inside of the loop. `$i++;` initialize it before the loop to suppress and notices

Comment: I would like to display the ID near each play that's in xml, as for now, all i got is 0 0 0 0 0... etc, can i add something on first column to make auto increment all the players?

Comment: If `0` is the value you get from the api you really shouldn't display them otherwise. That's lying :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is have a variable for that:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($players as $player)
{
    echo "<ul>
            <li id=\"number-$i\">$i.</li>
            <li id=\"nickname-$i\">$player->name</li>
            <li id=\"score-$i\">$player->score</li>
            <li id=\"time-$i\">$player->time</li>
          </ul>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @Vladimir Cvejic: Please see the edits of the answer, next to counting for the player you need to also create unique IDs for the id attributes across your HTML document. The answer shows that now, instead of the id attribute you might have wanted to use the class attribute as well (probably, just assuming what you aimed for).

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0; //Counter variable
foreach( $players as $player ) {
    $i++; //Increment the counter for each iteration
    echo "
        <ul>
        <li id=\"number\">$player->pid.</li>
        <li id=\"nickname\">$player->name</li>
        <li id=\"score\">$player->score</li>
        <li id=\"time\">$player->time</li>
        </ul>";
}
echo 'There were ' . $i . ' players in total';
```